# How to broadcast result from OpenMP single block

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm stuck with what looks a trivial problem (perhaps it's just too early in the day). From a function which is called within an `omp parallel` region I want to return a value which (1) must be same on every thread but (2) is computed in an `omp single` block. How can I do that? Here is a small code snippet:

```
// must work correctly when called from within omp parallel region
// this version is flawed. please suggest corrections
int func(vector<int>&args)
{
  int x;
#pragma omp single
  x = foo(args);    // foo() must be called in single block
                    // would need to broadcast x to all threads here
  return x;         // error: x only set for thread which executed foo()
}

// possible usage (elsewhere, you're not allowed to change this code)
#pragma omp parallel
{
   /* ... */
   int y = func(args);
   /* ... */
}
```

One rather inelegant solution would be to cast the`single` block into a `parallel for` with `reduction`:

```
int func(types args)
{
  int x=0;
#pragma omp for reduction(+:x)
  for(int i=0; i<1; ++i)
    x = foo(args);
  return x;
}
```

But surely, there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple - just append the `copyprivate(x)` clause, which does exactly that - it broadcasts the value(s) of the instance(s) of the listed private variables used in the `single` construct to the other threads:

```c
int func(vector<int>&args)
{
  int x;
#pragma omp single copyprivate(x)
  x = foo(args);    // foo() must be called in single block
                    // would need to broadcast x to all threads here
  return x;
}
```